# what does " int pix = (0xff & ((int) first[ij])); " mean?

Tags: java, android

The following code is part of a  working camera app that detects motion and saves preview, painting the moving parts red.

```
public class RgbMotionDetection implements IMotionDetection {
that detects motion       
private static final int mPixelThreshold = 50; // Difference in pixel (RGB)
private static final int mThreshold = 10000; // Number of different pixels


private static int[] mPrevious = null;
private static int mPreviousWidth = 0;
private static int mPreviousHeight = 0;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public int[] getPrevious() {
    return ((mPrevious != null) ? mPrevious.clone() : null);
}

protected static boolean isDifferent(int[] first, int width, int height) {
    if (first == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    if (mPrevious == null) return false;
    if (first.length != mPrevious.length) return true;
    if (mPreviousWidth != width || mPreviousHeight != height) return true;

    int totDifferentPixels = 0;
    for (int i = 0, ij = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++, ij++) {
            int pix = (0xff & ((int) first[ij]));
            int otherPix = (0xff & ((int) mPrevious[ij]));

            // Catch any pixels that are out of range
            if (pix < 0) pix = 0;
            if (pix > 255) pix = 255;
            if (otherPix < 0) otherPix = 0;
            if (otherPix > 255) otherPix = 255;

            if (Math.abs(pix - otherPix) >= mPixelThreshold) {
                totDifferentPixels++;
                // Paint different pixel red
                first[ij] = Color.RED;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'd like to understand this fully in order to be able to modify.

The line that really puzzles me is:

```
 int pix = (0xff & ((int) first[ij]));
```

What does it do?

thanks

Dave

Comment: `0xff` is a hexadecimal integer literal. `&` is the bitwise AND operator. `(int)` is a cast. `first[ij]` is an array access expression.

Comment: `int pix = (0xff & ((int) first[ij]));` is same as `int pix = (int) first[ij];`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No. Try it with any value above 255.

Comment: @his Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me if I explain something now that you know but I want to make this a self contained answer.

The colors of a pixel can be stored in an integer. An integer in Java consist of four bytes, a color typically (in this context) is represented with four bytes: One byte each for red, green, and blue, the last byte for transparency. The mix of the subpixels on screen results in the observed color.

So the following integer represents a color:

```
0    0    f    f    c    c    a    a      (Hexadecimal representation)
0000 0000 1111 1111 1100 1100 1010 1010   (Binary representation)
Transp.-- Red------ Green---- Blue-----   (Color interpretation)
                               16764074   (Decimal representation, quite useless here)
```

In this case the first two bytes (00) represent the transparency, ff the red subpixel, cc the green, aa the blue.

If we want to get only a single part of this, e.g. the blue subpixel, we need a bit mask.

```
0000 0000 1111 1111 1100 1100 1010 1010   (Binary representation)
&                                         (Binary AND: Return 1 if both bits are 1)
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111   (Bitmask for blue, in hex 0x000000ff)
=
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010 1010
```

This is the result of the operation in the line you mention, it just uses the shorthand hex interpretation for the mask:

```
int pix = (0xff & ((int) first[ij]));
```

As the array `first` already is an `int` array the cast of `first[ij]` is useless.

If you want another part of the pixel, say the green part, you need to shift the mask (or use a hardcoded value) and need to shift back the result:

```
00ffccaa
&
0000ff00 Hardcoded, alternative: ff << 8
=
0000cc00
```

Shift the result to the *rightmost position* within the integer

```
0000cc00 >> 8 = 000000cc
```

Similar with 16 and 24 for red resp. transparency.

So the line gives you the value of the *blue subpixel* of the pixel. This value is in the range of 0..255, as these are the only values possible with eight bits (when interpreted as unsigned byte or stored in a Java `int` as it is done here; Java `byte`s are signed and wouldn't use that decimal representation but -128..127); any check for other values is useless here.

Comment: Although I knew most of this, but thank you for putting this all together.

Answer (score 1):

I think that here it tries to get the value of the pixel but in a range of 0 to 255, so it uses the mask 0xFF to delete all the bits in a higher position than 8.

But I don't understand why it uses

```
            if (pix < 0) pix = 0;
            if (pix > 255) pix = 255;
```

When the pix variable can't be higher than 255